# Android 2.2: Turning of screen under certain times of the day by code

Tags: android, screen

I would like to know if there is any way to turn off the screen on an android device on for example 19.00-22.00 every day. I have some tablets running in kiosk mode, and i want the screens to turn off when no one is using them and the store is closed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Screens will turn off automatically, if you have that set up properly in the device settings.

You can use `AlarmManager` and a `WakeLock` to arrange to keep the device screen awake during business hours. Have the `AlarmManager` start up a service that acquires the `WakeLock` and waits until closing time. You will need to use `startForeground()` in the service to prevent Android from killing off your service.

In the real world, this implementation would suck, as it forces you to keep a service running all the time -- if you let the service shut down, you lose the `WakeLock` and can never `release()` it, so the screen will never shut off. So, outside of this sort of kiosk thing, I do not recommend this technique.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The thing is that i dont want the screen to turn off when the store is open. Therefore i use "FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON". Since i just started developing apps, would you mind giving me a code sample? Thanks again

Comment: @Johan: "The thing is that i dont want the screen to turn off when the store is open." -- that's what the `WakeLock` is for. "Therefore i use "FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON"" -- that only works if your activity is on-screen, which it might not be. "would you mind giving me a code sample?" -- I do not really have a code sample for your scenario, since it runs counter to what I would recommend normal developers do.