# Android wakelock question

Tags: android, wakelock

Could someone please show me a sample code snippet where you use two buttons; one to turn off and one to turn on the screen. I cant get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620046/android-2-2-turning-of-screen-under-certain-times-of-the-day-by-code)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question properly. A wake lock is set in your application so that the device screen does not turn off after a particular span of time. how ever you are advised to use this `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON` flag and is the best way

[Force Screen On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on/2134602#2134602)

Comment: Poor explanation, my bad. I would like a timer to turn on and off the screen at certain points of the day. For example: If (hourOfDay == 12) screen = on; else off

Answer (score 0):

Erm, when the screen is off, how are you hoping to display a button? Unless you mean hardware buttons, in which case I think only the power button can turn the screen back on.